# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ converges

Tags: calculus

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real number, let $\{n_k\}$ be an increasing sequence of positive integer and let $A_n=a_{n_k}+a_{n_{k+1}}+...+a_{n_{k+1}-1}$ for $k \in N$. Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ converges. Is the converse true?

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges implies that $lim _{n_>\infty} a_n =0$, can I conclude that $A_n$ ->$0$ as well, even if I can conclude that, it still doesn't prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ converges, am I correct?

Comment: You are correct that a limit going to zero is not sufficient to prove convergence.  The common example of that is the harmonic series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$ \sum_{k=1}^m A_k=\sum_{k=n_1}^{n_{m+1}-1}a_k.$$
Except for a fixed finite contribution $\sum_{k=1}^{n_1-1}a_k$, the right hand side is a partial sum of the convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$, hence is a convergent sequence, hence the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ converges.

A counterexample for the converse: Let $n_k=2k$ and $a_k=(-1)^k$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe you're simply "adding parenthesis" to your series (If $n_1\neq 1$, the you're only missing finitely many initial terms, so you're still good). The converse is not true, for example, take Grandi's series in the form $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots$

Comment: May I have a question, let $S_n$ be the Grandi's series, isn't $S_n=1$ for $n$ is odd and $S_n=0$ for even $n$? if so how can $S_n$ be convergent?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif That's my point. But if you "add parenthesis" and sum them in pairs, the sequence is now convergent. See?

Comment: oh, I see your point, after I add the parenthesis, the series will converges to $0$. But can you tell me, why am I allow to do that? because the addition is associative on the set of real number?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif It is not a matter of "are we allowed", rather, it is a matter of "what happens if we do?" The point here is that we cannot do it and hope the convergence is preserved.